# Is there a typescript for Elixir?

Tags: javascript, typescript, elixir

As TypeScript is a superset of Javascript, enabling developers to define types, which can be checked during compile time.

Is there a typescript for Elixir, which too is a dynamic language?

A superset of Elixir which enables type checking during compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elixir there is [typespec](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html), but I'm afraid, there is no tool that works in compilation phase that performs checks of the types. However, there is a third party, well known and commonly used tool - Dialyzer (for Erlang), and [Dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir) that makes using Dialyzer in Elixir projects easier. It analyses your code using typespecs provided.

Please, take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/JT0ECYZ9FaQ) video, as it provides great explanation in this area (not only how to use Dialyzer, how to understand error messages, but also how to annotate your functions etc.).

For more information about typespecs in Elixir, check also official [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html) page.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's [typespec](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html). It allows you to define custom types and specify expected types of function inputs and outputs. It's nowhere as powerful as something like Haskell's type system, but it helps you to build some safety net around your code. But you cannot declare the types of individual variables so that they can be checked at compile time.

[Dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) is a third party static analysis tool that you can use to check the correctness of your code. Along with type errors, it checks for unreachable code and unnecessary tests. There's an easy to understand [chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer) about dialyzer in Learn You Some Erlang book so I recommend you to check it out if you're interested.